# oauth 2.0 software for generating 40 character tokens in autodesk-forge

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

What is the recommended oauth 2.0 authentication software for generating autodesk-forge tokens? I am working through the autodesk forge tutorial and need to generate my 40 character token for my oauth 2.0 authentication. I have looked into both postman and cygwin to generate the token. Are these softwares what I should be using to generate my tokens? Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are looking to develop. The tokens get generated by the Authentication API which is REST based, so there are many ways to obtain it. We have develop different SDK's that can help you with the development of your application, currently we have tutorials to do authentication of a 2 legged or 3 legged token with

- NodeJS
- Net
- Java
- PHP
- Go

You can find that tutorial material here: http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/

Also If you are testing the endpoints and you need a token just to pass in subsequent REST calls you can use either Postman, Insomnia Rest or do it with cURL directly from cygwin or a linux based terminal.

Check these tutorials I have created in the past.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3-legged-oauth-2-using-insomnia-rest

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation